# Invalid JSON decoding in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have wrote a script to login into another website in PHP
When I log in, the page returns a JSON response where inside there is an URL
In that url there is a session parameter that I want to store in a PHP variable

the response looks like this:

```
{
    status:{
        err_code:0,
        err_text:""
    },
    url:"https://example.com/foo/bar?parameter=1&ID=54SomeCasualLettersAndNumbersWithAT@&otherparam=blah2"
}
```

I have tried to parse the JSON but the format is invalid and now I don't know what to do..
Is it a good idea to count the characters of the response and get the specify ones that I need?
They are form the 112nd to the 123rd

Comment: The JSON is invalid because the keys are not enclosed in quotes as they should be. You may need to use a regex here, eg. `/url:"(.*?)"/` - it boldly assumes that a URL will not itself contain quotes ;)

Comment: The problem is actually that this is *not* a JSON response. It looks more like a piece of JavaScript. Do you have any control over the page that generates this response? If so, I'd fix it on that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
{
    status:{
        err_code:0,
        err_text:""
    },
    url:"https://example.com/foo/bar?parameter=1&ID=54SomeCasualLettersAndNumbersWithAT@&otherparam=blah2"
}
DATA;

$regex = '~url:"([^"]+)"~';
preg_match($regex, $string, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

The url will be in `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

That response is malformed JSON and is more of a javascript object. You should be able to use a JSON5 parser to get the data you need. Here's one I found in Packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/hiroto-k/json5-php

Hope that helps.